# Can't push with Mercurial: abort: error: ''

Tags: mercurial, push, commit, bitbucket

I'm trying to push my changes into a Mercurial [Bitbucket.org](https://bitbucket.org/) repository, but while pushing, suddenly it aborts with the following empty error:

```
abort: error: ''
```

What does it mean? How can I avoid this error?

**Note**: based on my tries, push doesn't fail always. Sometimes it finishes correctly. But I want to know what this error means. I can't try again and again until push doesn't fail.

Comment: show **real full output** of `hg push -v --debug` for beginning

Comment: I've tried to push with `-v --debug` options, but no additional info is shown. It shows pushing process with its percentaje and, suddenly, the same empty error again: `abort: error: ''`

Comment: What version of Mercurial do you have (`hg version`)? How large is the group of changesets you're pushing?

Comment: I'm using version `2.2.2`, and this errors occurs with both large changesets (100MB) and small ones (6MB)

Comment: Please post the output of `hg push -v --debug --traceback`, to get the internal function which failed. You might also want to ask on the mailing list or on IRC (http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/MailingLists, http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/IRC)

Comment: Is the git plugin enabled and you have one or more subrepositories? That seems to be an ongoing problem...

Comment: Here is the exception traceback: http://pastebin.com/PD328VJB